# Error deploy web apps to Azure visual studio 2017

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying an Web app to Azure using Visual Studio 2017.

The web app is using windows authentication & gets deployed without any error but gets redirected to `https://localhost:44334/`

As I am using Windows authentication it correctly uses my azure credentials to log me in and redirects to the localhost.

In the web config I changed the key for `ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri` to the Azure app service url.

It works fine on localhost but when I changed the webconfig url it still redirects the page to `https:/localhost:4434` and gives an error `Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="265751ce-5142-4d79-ba57-86ab32293f9e" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="myaccount.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="09bacfbd-47ef-4465-9265-3546f2eaf6bc" />

        <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://myportal.azurewebsites.net/" />
```

I followed this link `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2`

Is there a web config or setting that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to publish you web app to azure and use azure credentials to login in , you should not choose **Windows authentication**, this authentication verify you local windows's account. I suggest you using **Work or School Accounts**. Then create App registration and set the `web.config`.

2.As for the problem you occurred ,it didn't occur to me. Because if you publish the web app with **Windows authentication**, even you set the `web.config` the app won't open the authentication window. And if you run it on local and it redirects to localhost, this is completely OK.

I suggest you using **Work or School Accounts** and deploying it, if you still have questions, please let me know.